VBA macro & drop-down list
I have VBA code in sheet to allow multiple selections from a drop-down list.  However this macro applies to all other drop-downs i have on the sheet, how do I bind it to a specific drop-down list ?
Don't know how to bind the VBA code to a specific drop-down list
